# Cannot compile HPLIP

Tags: printing, compiling, hp, hplip, snmp

I have Ubuntu 17.10. My kernel version is 4.14.21-041421-generic.
I have downloaded HPLIP 3.17.11 run file from the website.
Unfortunately I am unable to compile it. After running the `.run` file, it starts `./configure`, which throws an error regarding `net-snmp`.

In particular, these are the last lines of configure:

```
checking for cups ppd install... no
checking for foomatic-rip-hplip install... no
checking for qt5... no
checking for qt4... yes
checking for qt3... no
checking for policykit... no
checking for host machine platform... x86_64
checking for CRYPTO_free in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: cannot find net-snmp support (or --disable-network-build)
```

SNMP is installed:

```
snmp is already the newest version (5.7.3+dfsg-1.7ubuntu1).
```

and `libsnmp-dev` is also installed (version 5.7.3).

Comment: ? Can't the default hplip (3.17.7+repack0-3) packages be used ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/hplip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two moments here

1. hplip-gui is [well-packaged on 17.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hplip&searchon=names&suite=artful&section=all) - you will get 3.17.7, you can install this version with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
   ```
2. If you need to compile this package you should do the following:

   enable source code repositories in `software-properties-gtk` then get build-dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep hplip-gui
   ```

   and then run `./configure`, `make` and so on.

Comment: I can't use the stock version because it's bugged, and your second solution doesn't work! `You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: you should kindly enable source repositories (see update above).

Comment: It worked. I think it was probably `libssl-dev` what were missing, since I have read that openssl was needed for hplip to find snmp

Comment: Sorry, it still gives an error when I try to install the printer :( `Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
error: Plugin download failed with error code = 8
error:  file does not match its checksum. File may have been corrupted or altered
`

Comment: We can not fix your network problems here.

Comment: It appears not to be a network problem [see here](https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/). Anyway I managed to download the file manually

Comment: which printer do you own please?

Comment: HP LaserJet P1102

Answer (score 0):

hplip has multiple dependencies like libsnmp, libcups, libusb, libdbus-1. Make sure that you install all of these before running ./configure. If you have all these, the installation runs smoothly.