# HP Laserjet 1020 does not work in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, hplip, laserjet

I installed hplip and etc, but still my printer (HP LaserJet 1020) is not working when I'm trying to print a test page. A massage shows me that the printer printed this job but nothing happens on printer. I tested anything.

Please help and advice something.

Comment: Please be more specific, how did you installed it, the whole procedure..
when you type `lsusb` do you see your printer among other usb devices?

Comment: #spaceman11x yes when im typing """lsusb""" ican see my device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot compile HPLIP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011024/cannot-compile-hplip)

Comment: #N0rbert  but my hplip is installed whiteout any problem

Comment: Please edit the question with additional information instead of burying the information in comments

Comment: Do you have the driver properly installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

I've configured it today for 19.10 the next way.

First of all I've tried to run `hp-check` in terminal to see what is wrong with it and it said it requires some packages that are not installed. But it didn't help to resolve the issue. Finally, I've realized I need to install the newest `phlip` from [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip) and install it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x hplip-3.20.3.run
sh ./hplip-3.20.3.run
```

I had previous version of hplip, so current version of phlip asked if I want to remove it to avoid conflicts and I've accepted. Then I've run the `sh ./hplip-3.20.3.run` command again because of I didn't see *hp utils* installed.

The second time I was answering the next way:

```
Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : a
Is "Ubuntu 19.10" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y
Please enter the sudoer (spacer)'s password:     # here I've entered my user's password
Please read the installation notes. Press <enter> to continue or 'q' to quit: # here I've hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y
HPLIP-3.20.3 exists, this may conflict with the new one being installed.
Do you want to ('i'= Remove and Install*, 'q'= Quit)?    :i
```

Then it asked me `Do you want to check for HPLIP updates?. (y=yes*, n=no) : y` and I've said `yes`, but then interrupted that process.

But without hplip plugin it refused to work. So I've run:

```
hp-doctor
```

It said everything is OK except the

```
error: Required plug-in status: Not installed
```

and then it asked if I want to install the plugin:

```
Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
Plugin's are missing. Press 'y' to install the plugin(y=yes*, n=no):y

-----------------------------------------
| PLUG-IN INSTALLATION FOR HPLIP 3.20.3 |
-----------------------------------------

  Option      Description                                       
  ----------  --------------------------------------------------
  d           Download plug-in from HP (recommended)            
  p           Specify a path to the plug-in (advanced)          
  q           Quit hp-plugin (skip installation)                

Enter option (d=download*, p=specify path, q=quit) ? d

error: Unable to recieve key from keyserver
Do you still want to install the plug-in? (y=yes, n=no*, q=quit) ? y

Do you accept the license terms for the plug-in (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y
Please enter the sudoer (spacer)'s password: 

Downloading firmware to device hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_1020?serial=FN0D69G...
Firmware download successful.
```

After that it prints a test page and documents.